# TSQL - Case error with syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax-error

Someone can tell me why I have error

```
select TrN_FPlID as Platnosc
CASE 
WHEN TrN_FPlID  = '1' THEN 'Gotowka'
WHEN TrN_FPlID  = '3' THEN 'Przelew'
from CDN.TraNag
```

and I have this error:

```
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
```

Comment: Missing comma before the case. (And missing end for the case.)

Comment: Aside: If `TrN_FPlID` is an `int` then the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) will force SQL Server to convert the strings, e.g. `'3'`, to `int` for comparison. In that case just use `TrN_FPlID = 3` rather than mixing data types.

Answer (score 1):

> You need a comma to separate the selected columns.

```
select 
    TrN_FPlID as Platnosc,
    (CASE 
        WHEN TrN_FPlID  = '1' THEN 'Gotowka'
        WHEN TrN_FPlID  = '3' THEN 'Przelew'
    END) as ColumnName
from CDN.TraNag
```

> Always put an `END` syntax after you have finish your `CASE` statement
>   Add `as YourColName` after the case syntax like you have done to TrN_FPlID
>   Another way of doing this

```
select 
    TrN_FPlID as Platnosc,
    iif(TrN_FPlID  = '1','Gotowka',iif(TrN_FPlID  = '3','Przelew',null)) as ColumnName
from CDN.TraNag
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing comma before case and the case statement is missing End.

Conditional expression is not required for each case, while checking for the equal = operator.

```
    select TrN_FPlID as Platnosc,
    CASE TrN_FPlID 
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Gotowka'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'Przelew'
    end
    from CDN.TraNag
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation corresponding to your DBMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

First, you are missing a coma before the `CASE`, second your `CASE` is missing an `END` and third, the syntax `WHEN field = value` is not valid.

Comment: The third, `WHEN column = value` part is fine.

Comment: Okey! I fixed that. Thank you.
Can you tell me how can I set name for result from case, becasue I have (No column name)

Comment: @BElluu, you just add "as NewColumAlias" after 'end'.